# Cannot click button within relativelayout that has linearlayout

Tags: android, android-layout

Below is my xml file with problem.
When I remove the linear layout and let spinner in relative_layout it works
fine but as soon as I put them in Linear_layout, button and edit_box cannot be pressed. Please help.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/trainid"
        android:hint="@string/train"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:text="@string/search"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/traindetails"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/trainid"
        android:text="" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/traindetails"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/selectcurrentstation"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            android:layout_weight="0.5" />
        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/selecttargetstation"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            android:layout_weight="0.5" />

    </LinearLayout>




    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/selectcurrentstation" >

        <TableLayout 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:stretchColumns="1"
            android:id="@+id/table" />

    </ScrollView>




</RelativeLayout>
```

When I change my xml file to this it works fine. But I want the above layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/trainid"
        android:hint="@string/train"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:focusable="true" />


    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:text="@string/search"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:focusable="true" />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/traindetails"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/trainid"
        android:text="" />




    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/selectcurrentstation"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:layout_below="@id/traindetails" />
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/selecttargetstation"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:layout_below="@id/selectcurrentstation" />






    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/selectcurrentstation" >

        <TableLayout 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:stretchColumns="1"
            android:id="@+id/table" />

    </ScrollView>




</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: How exactly you want to implement it ?

Comment: Actually, I want two spinners inside linear_layout, but when I do that I lose buttons. I don't know why I am losing them that way.

Comment: That you have already kept. What exactly problem you are facing ?

Comment: But the button cannot be clicked this way, that is the problem.

Comment: Have you implemented click listener of button ? I have tried to put button in linearlayout and its getting clicked.

Comment: Yes, I have done that. Infact when i bring two spinners out of the LinearLayout and remove LinearLayout, it works fine.

Comment: Its working perfectly. I have tried to put edittext and button inside linearlayout.

Comment: Please check the edited code, maybe i am not explaining well.

Comment: your edited code is also working.. I am able to write text on edittext and able to click on button even.

Comment: I don't know why is it not working in mine. Can you guess what could be the problem. I am testing it on "xiaomi redmi1s", mintarget sdk = 8 in android manifest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MAke a little changes in the 1st code and your code will work fine.

1. In the linear layour (user as parent of two spinner) give it the id ex. linear_layout1.
2. The spinner layout(used as parent of table layout) change the layout_below id to the above ie linear_layout1.

   ```
   <RelativeLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >

   <AutoCompleteTextView
       android:id="@+id/trainid"
       android:hint="Train"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


   <Button
       android:id="@+id/button"
       android:text="Search"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/traindetails"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@id/trainid"
       android:text="" />


   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/selectstation1"
       android:layout_below="@id/traindetails"

       android:orientation="horizontal" >

       <Spinner
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:id="@+id/selectcurrentstation"
           android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
           android:layout_weight="0.5" />
       <Spinner
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:id="@+id/selecttargetstation"
           android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
           android:layout_weight="0.5" />

   </LinearLayout>




   <ScrollView
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:layout_below="@id/selectstation1" >

       <TableLayout
           xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:stretchColumns="1"
           android:id="@+id/table" />

   </ScrollView>
   </RelativeLayout>
   ```